Mock new Date or System.currentTimeMillis
I am setting up tests using Groovy and the Spock framework. My tests depend on the passage of time, and the services in question use new Date() for some rules. Because of this, I would like to modify new Date() in my test to, for example, return a date 7 days in the future.
I have tried using metaClass, Mockito, and PowerMockito, among others, but none of these scenarios seem to work, as it appears we cannot mock static methods or native methods. Is there any solution for this scenario?

With Spock's Mockito mock maker, you can mock static methods. But you seem to wish to mock constructor calls, which currently you need tools like Mockito, Sarek or PowerMock for. If done correctly, you can use those tools. But actually, if this is about your own and not third-party code, refactoring the code under test to use dependency injection instead of instantiating dependencies inside the code yourself is a way more prudent approach, just like Leonard describes it in his answer. Having to use extra tools for testing on top of Spock is usually a code smell.

I would urge you to use the java.time.* api and not rely on the legacy java.util.Date class.
Then you can simple inject a custom java.time.Clock to simulate time, like Spock's MutableClock.
public class AgeFilter implements Predicate<LocalDate> {
  private final Clock clock;
  private final int age;

  public AgeFilter(Clock clock, int age) {                                       
    this.clock = clock;
    this.age = age;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean test(LocalDate date) {
    return Period.between(date, LocalDate.now(clock)).getYears() >= age;      
  }
}

def "AgeFilter reacts to time"() {
  given:
  ZonedDateTime defaultTime = ZonedDateTime.of(2018, 6, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, ZoneId.of('UTC'))
  MutableClock clock = new MutableClock(defaultTime)                                       
  AgeFilter ageFilter = new AgeFilter(clock,18)                                            

  LocalDate birthday = defaultTime.minusYears(18).plusDays(1).toLocalDate()

  expect:
  !ageFilter.test(birthday)                                                                

  when:
  clock + Duration.ofDays(1)                                                               

  then:
  ageFilter.test(birthday)                                                                 
}

